# Receiving notifications in Ionic mobile app in background and foreground through Node.js (firebase-admin)

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have an Ionic mobile application that receives notifications from the Firebase console. The application correctly receives notifications in background and foreground. However, when I send notifications from Node.js with firebase-admin plugin, only foreground notification arrives. Notifications do not arrive when the application is in the background.

What could be the problem? Does anyone know why the mobile app receive notifications in background with Firebase console but not with Node.js?

Thanks for any idea.

This is the code in the mobile application (app.component.ts):

```
this.fcm.subscribeToTopic('all');

platform.ready().then(() => {

  this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
    console.log(token);

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: '¡new notification!',
      message: token,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('cancel button');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'OK',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('ok button');
            this.navCtrl.push('DetailPage');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  alert.present();

  });

  this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
    alert('message received')
    if(data.wasTapped) {
     console.info("Received in background");
    } else {
     console.info("Received in foreground");
    };
  });

  statusBar.styleDefault();
  splashScreen.hide();
});
```

This is the code in Node.js:

```
var sys = require("util");
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('./xxxx.json');

var registrationToken ="xxxxxx";

admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
   databaseURL: "https://xxxxx"
});

var message = {
data: {
  score: '850',
  time: '2:45'
    },
    token: registrationToken
};

admin.messaging().send(message)
.then(function(response) {
    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log("Error sending message", error);
});
```

Comment: You have some solution...